# Angular promise returns 404, does not trigger finally

Tags: angularjs, promise

Am I misunderstanding promises and finally?

I am posting to an API which is not built yet. It returns a 404 - as I expect it to - but the controller function AdminManifestService.postManifest never finishes, so I have a spinner (bound to vm.processingButton) forever.

Shouldn't it return the failed promise as soon as it gets the 404?

Controller:

```
    vm.sendManifest = function () {
        vm.processingButton = true;
        var manifest = vm._buildManifest();
        AdminManifestService.postManifest(manifest)
            .then (
                function success(response) {
                    toastr.success("Manifest has been sent.");
                },
                function fail(response) {
                    toastr.error(response.data);
                }
            )
            .finally(function(){
                vm.processingButton = false;
            }
        );
    }
```

Service:

```
function adminManifestService($http, $q, ngAuthSettings) {

    var dataSource = 'api';

    // GET User Markups
    var _postManifest = function (data) {

        return $q (function(resolve, reject) {
            switch (dataSource) {
                case 'api': //staging - live api data
                    return $http({
                        method: 'post',
                        url: serviceBase + 'api/Admin/Manifest/',
                        data: data
                    }).then(function(results) {
                         resolve(results.data);
                    });
                    break;
                default: // dev - local json
                    resolve();
            }
        });
    };

    adminManifestService.postManifest = _postManifest;

    return adminManifestService;
}
```

Comment: `finally` is a method in `$q` promises, that OP is using. See [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot parse that sentence. What is the problem? What is the solution?

Comment: There was a comment (now deleted) asking how you came by with `finally` since its not part of the Promises spec. It indeed is not part of the spec but comes with `$q` :)

Answer (score 2):

You never reject the promise in your `adminManifestService`, so the `$http` rejection is swallowed.

Beware! You are a victim of the [promise anti-pattern](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/).

Instead of wrapping your `$http` promise with `$q`, simply return it:

```
var _postManifest = function (data) {
  if (dataSource !== 'api') {
    return $q.resolve();
  }

  return $http({
    method: 'post',
    url: serviceBase + 'api/Admin/Manifest/',
    data: data
  }).then(function(results) {
    return results.data;
  });
};
```

You may also add an `errorCallback` in here too:

```
var _postManifest = function (data) {
  if (dataSource !== 'api') {
    return $q.resolve();
  }

  return $http({
    method: 'post',
    url: serviceBase + 'api/Admin/Manifest/',
    data: data
  }).then(function(results) {
    return results.data;
  }, function(results) {
    // Note that we need to return a rejected promise
    return $q.reject(results.data);
  });
};
```

So that you can use your service with minimum work:

```
adminManifestService.postManifest(manifest)
  .then(function() {
    toastr.success("Manifest has been sent.");
  }, toastr.error)      // You can just send `toastr.error` here
  .finally(function(){
    vm.processingButton = false;
  });
```

Comment: Hm. I originally did not have that $q in there, and when I ran into problems with the finally, I posted it on SO, and some ones suggested this as the solution. So now you're suggesting I pull it back out. OK, I'll try that. Thx.

Comment: Please read the link I provided above; `$http` already returns a promise, you don’t need `$q` here (except if you want to reject with an updated rejection – see the second code block) :)

Comment: Ah. OK. I know why the $q is in there now. Because the service is NOT necessarily a promise. Updating OP. Sorry about the wild goose chase.
I guess, since I've got a local implementation, I'll have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

`$http` service returns `promise` itself, that means its not necessary to wrap anything in `$q`. Here is working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ySmA3Rd5DB6JQp50NVlM?p=preview) with simplified proof of concept.

```
function adminManifestService($http, $q, ngAuthSettings) {

    var dataSource = 'api';

    // GET User Markups
    var _postManifest = function (data) {

        switch (dataSource) {
            case 'api': //staging - live api data
                return $http({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: serviceBase + 'api/Admin/Manifest/',
                    data: data
                })
                break;
            default: // dev - local json
                return new Promise(function(resolve){
                    resolve({data:"dev data"})
                })
        }
    };

    adminManifestService.postManifest = _postManifest;

    return adminManifestService;
}
```

Controller

```
vm.sendManifest = function () {
    vm.processingButton = true;
    var manifest = vm._buildManifest();
    AdminManifestService.postManifest(manifest)
        .then (
            function success(response) {
                toastr.success("Manifest has been sent.");
                vm.processingButton = false;
            }
        )
        .catch(function(err){
              toastr.error(err);
              vm.processingButton = false;
        });
}
```